# Concentration inequality for sparse logistic regression estimation error

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

In reading [Robust 1-bit compressed sensing and sparse logistic regression: A convex programming approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1212) by Plan and Vershynin, I came across an unfamiliar inequality.  At the end of the proof of Corollary 3.3, it is claimed that
$$
\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha) \geq \frac{1}{6} \min \{ \alpha, 1 \},
$$
where $0 < \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $g \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is a standard normal random variable.

My approach was to separate this into two cases: $\alpha \leq 1$ and $\alpha > 1$.  First, note that $\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} > 0.39$.

If $\alpha \leq 1$, then $\min \{ \alpha, 1 \} = \alpha$ and
$$
P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha) \geq P(|g| \leq 1) > 0.68.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha) \geq (0.39) (0.68) \alpha \geq \frac{1}{6} \min \{ \alpha, 1 \}.
$$

I am struggling with the case $\alpha > 1$.  Here, we have $\min \{ \alpha, 1 \} = 1$ so
$$
\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha)
= \min \{ \alpha, 1 \} \cdot  \frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot \alpha \cdot P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha).
$$
It seems that one then needs to find a lower bound $c$
$$
\alpha \cdot P(|g| \leq 1 / \alpha) \geq c
$$
satisfying $\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot c \geq \frac{1}{6}$.  Stated differently, given $\alpha > 1$, does there exist a constant $c$ satisfying $\frac{\text{sech}^2(1 / 2)}{2} \cdot c \geq \frac{1}{6}$ such that
$$
P(|g| \geq 1 / \alpha) \leq 1 - \frac{c}{\alpha}?
$$

This is where I'm stuck.  The concentration inequalities I've considered (Cheybyshev, Vysochanskij–Petunin, etc.) are trivial for this $\alpha > 1$ case.  It there some other inequality that would be useful here?  Or, is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha>1$. Then $$P\{|g|\geq 1/\alpha\}\leq 1- \frac{c}{\alpha}\iff P\{|g|\leq 1/\alpha\}\geq c/\alpha$$
Indeed,
$$P\{|g|\leq 1/\alpha\} = \int_{-1/\alpha}^{1/\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx \geq \frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2\alpha^2} \geq \frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt e}$$
Taking $c = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi e}}$ and using a computer gives $$\frac{\mathrm{sech}^2(1/2)}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi e}} \approx 0.1903 \geq 0.167 \geq 1/6$$

Comment: Great, thank you!